# How to solve this scenario in a relational database schema?

Tags: relational-database

Let's assume I have the following tables (just as an example):

```
vehicle: {n̲a̲m̲e̲, type}
vehicle_type: {n̲a̲m̲e̲} // has 'car' and 'ship'
person: {i̲d̲, age}
container: {i̲d̲, color}
```

Now I want to note the gas consumption per year in a seperate table. But there a also attributes valid only for cars or for ships. Let's say cars can only transport persons and ships transport containers.

Now there are two solutions I currently can think of:

1. Make one big table for consumption with all attributes, although some doesn't make sense for either cars or ships. These invalid attributes then would have dummy values like `-` because they cannot be `null`:

   ```
   consumption: {v̲e̲h̲i̲c̲l̲e̲_̲n̲a̲m̲e̲, y̲e̲a̲r̲, p̲e̲r̲s̲o̲n̲s̲, c̲o̲n̲t̲a̲i̲n̲e̲r̲s̲, liters}
   ```
2. Make two tables, increasing complexity but having just valid attributes:

   ```
   consumption_cars: {v̲e̲h̲i̲c̲l̲e̲_̲n̲a̲m̲e̲, y̲e̲a̲r̲, p̲e̲r̲s̲o̲n̲s̲, liters}
   consumption_ships: {v̲e̲h̲i̲c̲l̲e̲_̲n̲a̲m̲e̲, y̲e̲a̲r̲, c̲o̲n̲t̲a̲i̲n̲e̲r̲s̲, liters}
   ```

In my real scenario there are more exclusive attributes, so in case 2 I'd have to create like 7 tables. I also thought of a `is-a` relationship for the consumption tables, but I'd like to avoid it since it doesn't work very well in practice (at least that's my previous experience).

Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend keeping common attributes together, and distinct attributes separate:

```
consumption: {vehicle_name PK, year PK, liters}
transport_cars: {vehicle_name PK, year PK, persons}
transport_ships: {vehicle_name PK, year PK, containers}
```